# Using the function $f'\left( x \right) = \left( {{e^{\left( {f\left( x \right) - g\left( x \right)} \right)}}} \right)g'\left( x \right)$

Tags: integration, functions

Let $f:R \to R\ $ and  $g:R \to R$ be two non-constant differentiable function. If $f'\left( x \right) = \left( {{e^{\left( {f\left( x \right) - g\left( x \right)} \right)}}} \right)g'\left( x \right)$  for all $x \in R$ and $f(1)=g(2)=1$, then which of the following statement is(are) true

(A) $f\left( 2 \right) < 1 - {\log _e}2$

(B) $f\left( 2 \right) > 1 - {\log _e}2$

(C) $g\left( 2 \right) > 1 - {\log _e}2$

(D) $g\left( 2 \right) < 1 - {\log _e}2$

My approach is as follow

$f'\left( x \right) = \left( {{e^{\left( {f\left( x \right) - g\left( x \right)} \right)}}} \right)g'\left( x \right)$

${e^{ - f\left( x \right)}}f'\left( x \right) = {e^{ - g\left( x \right)}}g'\left( x \right)$

$\int {{e^{ - f\left( x \right)}}f'\left( x \right)dx}  = \int {{e^{ - g\left( x \right)}}g'\left( x \right)dx}  + c$

$t = {e^{ - f\left( x \right)}} \Rightarrow dt =  - {e^{ - f\left( x \right)}}f'\left( x \right)dx\& u = {e^{ - g\left( x \right)}} \Rightarrow du =  - {e^{ - g\left( x \right)}}g'\left( x \right)dx$

$ - \int {dt}  =  - \int {du}  + c \Rightarrow  - t =  - u + c$

$ \Rightarrow  - {e^{ - f\left( x \right)}} =  - {e^{ - g\left( x \right)}} + c \Rightarrow  - {e^{ - f\left( 1 \right)}} =  - {e^{ - g\left( 1 \right)}} + c \Rightarrow  - {e^{ - 1}} =  - {e^{ - g\left( 1 \right)}} + c \Rightarrow c = {e^{ - g\left( 1 \right)}} - {e^{ - 1}}$

$ \Rightarrow  - {e^{ - f\left( 2 \right)}} =  - {e^{ - g\left( 2 \right)}} + c \Rightarrow c = {e^{ - g\left( 2 \right)}} - {e^{ - f\left( 2 \right)}} \Rightarrow c = {e^{ - 1}} - {e^{ - f\left( 2 \right)}}$

On comparing we get $ \Rightarrow {e^{ - g\left( 1 \right)}} - {e^{ - 1}} = {e^{ - 1}} - {e^{ - f\left( 2 \right)}} \Rightarrow {e^{ - g\left( 1 \right)}} + {e^{ - f\left( 2 \right)}} = 2{e^{ - 1}}$.

How do we procced this question

Answer (score 1):

$2e^{-1}=e^{-g(1)}+e^{-f(2)}>e^{-f(2)}$. Hence, $\ln 2 -1 >-f(2)$ which gives $f(2) >1-\ln 2$. So (B) is true which makes (A) false.For (C) and (D) just use the hypothesis that $g(2)=1$.

[I have written $\ln x$ for $log_2(x)$].